# Certain applications stopping all attempts at getting keystrokes

Tags: c#, .net, windows

So for work they have me writing a simple program for tracking employee efficiency within their workflow (things like using keyboard shortcuts, window locations, how often they need to look stuff up). Currently we want to track the 'F5' key (brings up next work item), 'Alt+Tab' (changes windows), 'Ctrl+V' (paste), but may be expanded as they find there are more shortcuts or things they want to track.

*Note* We are on windows 7, and using c# to write the tracking program.

In order to do this I wrote a low-level hooking library to capture the chosen keystrokes, send off the message down the hook chain and then add a note to a db that the key was used. The hooking library works great in All web browsers and most normal programs (except we don't actually care about browsers so we ignore everything done in them).

The issue is that the application that they use for managing their work (the program we actually care about tracking) some how stops our hooks from hooking and I do not know how. The application in question is TA2000 Desktop.

I know that with the way hooks work if an application fails to call `callnexthook()` within the LowLevelHooksTimeout period that the system kills the hook. So figuring maybe TA2000 was just taking to long or something I bumped up the timeout to 30 seconds (yes I know this is significantly more time than a hook should even need) but this had no effect.

The next thing I tried was implementing a tracking system based on the Raw Input API. And once again the tracking tracks on browsers, Microsoft office, notepad, and all the other programs I opened except it still is unable to track key press in TA2000.  This really surprised me because according to MSDN

> - An application does not have to detect or open the input device.
> - An application gets the data directly from the device, and processes the    data for its needs
> - An application can distinguish the source of the input even if it is from the same type of device. For example, two    mouse devices.

So if I am getting the data directly from the device how is TA2000 preventing me from also getting the key press?

The last thing I could think of trying was using dll injection on TA2000 to inject a hook. However this method seems risky because It is something neither I nor any other developer here has any experience with and the application we want to track is operation critical so messing it up can not happen and injecting code into its memory space seems like a good way to mess things up.

If someone could explain how TA2000 could be stopping me from tracking keystrokes and how to beat it or point me in a good direction I would be very appreciative.

p.s. This felt questionable as an appropriate question for the SO format but it also feels specific enough to be a viable question. So sorry if this is not a good question but I am at my wits end with this.

Comment: Is TA2000 Desktop an older version, or running in compatibility mode?  Until Windows 7, all keyboard and mouse input occurs in the form of window event messages that are sent to the application, but for old software or software that has been ported from another platform, this is not always the case.  I attempted to search for TA2000 Desktop, but found several different packages that are called some variation of that, so I couldn't tell which it is - is this the financial/investing package, or something else?  How likely is it that it is designed to prevent snooping from keyloggers?

Comment: @MattJordan Yes this is a finacial package used by our call center reps. It is certainly possible that it is designed to prevent snooping because it is being used in the finance industry, but I am not certain. And sadly TA2000 or at least the version we use is custom made for us so sadly finding a version on the web that is the same as the one we use wont happen.

Comment: The first step is to determine whether this might be a security "feature", or if it is just the way the software was designed.  I'd suggest using a process debugger on it, to see if it is hiding activity.  Do this in an isolated environment, since any kind of full monitoring software could slow it down quite a bit.  Sysinternals' Process Explorer might be a safe first approach - it doesn't log keystrokes, but it might show whether TA2000 is trying to hide what it is doing, in general.

Comment: So I got the Process explorer and when I select TALogon.exe in the Process list and mouse over it it says Path: [Access Denied] and it says Error opening process on the TAGui.exe. 
Also hurray for random downvotes!

Comment: Run it as an Administrator (File|Run As Administrator), and then choose File|Show Details For All Processes.  That may not help, it sounds like the financial software is locked down, but it would be helpful to know if this is an intentional security feature or just non-standard design.

Comment: Alright that fixed the access denied issue. And also fixed my other issue. It seems that If i start my hook program as admin it gets the keypresses fine.

Comment: @MattJordan I am not sure why I never thought to try running my code as admin but it seems that the issue was that TA2000 is run as admin so in order to interact with it I must also be admin. But thanks to you I now have my code up and running. If i was rich i would find you and hug you!

Comment: Glad I could help - I'm going to add this to an answer, in case you want to mark it answered - I think that should increase you to 11 points rather than 9, which I think allows you to do a bit more.  Your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This financial software package is secured to prevent snooping.  Running the key logging software as Administrator appears to fix this specific problem.  The security was identified initially using Sysinternals' Process Explorer, which is a great starting point for unexpected problems like this.